# Change in model not updated in view ngValue - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am facing an issue with angular's two way binding and ng-value directive.

There is a method binded to `ng-value` and when the value is changed else where it is not updated in the view. To solve this, I have registered a `$watch` but `$digest` is throwing this [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest). I dont know where I am going wrong and want to know the right approach in this situation.

I have posted the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myController">
 <button ng-click="change()">Change</button>
 <input type="text" ng-value="getData()" />
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
$scope.a = 0;

$scope.getData = function() {
    $scope.a = 50;
    return $scope.a;
}

$scope.change = function() {
    k = 1;
    $scope.a = 100;
    console.log($scope.a)
}

$scope.$watch('a', function() {
     $scope.$digest();
})
})
```

When I click the button `Change` the value of variable is changed but it is not updated in the view, so I tried `$digest` and `$apply` which is throwing this error.

> $digest already in progress

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-model` to make sure that the value in the input is properly tracked. It sounds like you only want `getData` to get the initial value of the input from a service. If that's correct, you can still call that function in your controller constructor:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.getData = function() {
    $scope.a = 50;
    return $scope.a;
  }

  $scope.change = function() {
    k = 1;
    $scope.a = 100;
    console.log($scope.a)
  }

  $scope.getData();
});
```

Then your HTML should look like this:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myController">
  <button ng-click="change()">Change</button>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a" />
</div>
```

Try it out on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TXf2gLdLFkiRrufKQC8W?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, but the plunker link is not working. When I click the change button, textbox is not updated.

Comment: What browser are you running this in? (because it works on my Chrome)

Comment: I also use Chrome. I assumed Angular would abstract away the browser differences. I'll update if I find a fix for it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just tried IE and Firefox, and they worked for me, too. I know "worked on my browser" doesn't solve the problem. I'm just at a loss for why it didn't work.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Thanks, It is working. But I can't take that ng-value out because I need to do some calculations for the text box. How I can achieve this with ng-value.

Comment: Again, I'm assuming `getData` is making some sort of service call. If so, you could edit the service to provide a method for subscribing to updates, and then have your controller handle updates by changing the value of the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `ng-model` then try like this

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.myText = 50;
    $scope.getData = function () {
        return $scope.myText;
    }

    $scope.change = function () {
        k = 1;
        $scope.myText = 100;
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="change()">Change</button>
    <input type="text" ng-value="getData()" />
</div>
```

Comment: @vishnu I guess this is what you are looking for, if then dont forget to cast your valuable vote and mark it as answer